# what is the difference between method(String str) and method(Final String str)

Tags: java, methods, arguments, keyword

The use of Final keyword inside the method argument puzzles me

```
public void helloWorld(String str)
{

}


public void helloWorld(Final String str)
{

}

What is the differences between them?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`public void helloWorld(final String str)` doesn't allow you to change the value of `str` locally inside the method, while without the final keyword, you can change it locally.

```
public void helloWorld(String str)
{
     str = "something"; // OK
}


public void helloWorld(final String str)
{
    str = "something"; // ERROR
}
```

Of course, even `helloWorld(String str)` can't change the value of the `String` passed to the method, since Java is a pass-by-value language.

Comment: Also what about int or any other data type.

Comment: @BelieveToLive The answer is the same for `int` and any other data type.